# Angular ng-controller not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in angular and can't able to find error in below code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Tutorial 2</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function testController($scope){
            $scope.data = {message: "test123"};
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="">
    <div ng-controller="testController">
        <!--<input type="text" ng-model="test.sfdc"/>-->
        <h1>{{data.message}}</h1>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code print `<<data.message>>` as output. Please let me know where I go wrong.

Comment: How new are you in angular? I would recommend getting some tutorial first.

Comment: ^ +1 - You've missed a number of elements and probably need a bit more of a grounding in Angular. Need to register your app, then register your controller with the app.

Comment: Thanks Seonixx, I am wroking on tutorials and its was not mentioned there that's why got stuck, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register the controller in your angular app.

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Tutorial 2</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">        
        var DummyCtrl = function ($scope){
            $scope.data = {message: "test123"};
        }
        angular.module('app', [])
        .controller('DummyCtrl', DummyCtrl);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="DummyCtrl">
        <!--<input type="text" ng-model="test.sfdc"/>-->
        <h1>{{data.message}}</h1>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined your angular module.

For example

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<html ng-app="app">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your controller with angular.

```
angluar.module(APP_NAME).controller("testController", testController);
```

Comment: where is module angular name?